# hits calculation in a graph using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

i am trying to calculate number of hits in a graph which has multiple edges i have written a small code in networkx which is as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab  as plot
g=nx.read_pajek("D:\Slash.net")
h,a=nx.hits(g)
```

But when I tried to execute the code I got following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx-1.7-py2.7.egg\networkx
\link_analysis\hits_alg.py", line 74, in hits
raise Exception("hits() not defined for graphs with multiedges.")
Exception: hits() not defined for graphs with multiedges.
```

Kindly have a look upon it
Thanks and regards!

Comment: Maybe your graph has multiedges.

Answer (score 1):

The `read_pajek` function returns `g` as a MultiGraph or MultiDiGraph. Convert it to a simple graph with `nx.Graph(g)`.